# Создание файла с названием на кириллице

Tags: java, utf-8, кириллица, cp1251

Нужна программа на java. Как исправить кодировку сохраняемого на телефон файла?

Имя файла должно быть строго русскими буквами, но сохраняется 2 файла: один - с правильным названием на кириллице, но без данных (вес файла - 0 байт), второй - с данными, но имя файла состоит из знаков %D0%A1 и так далее.

В сети полно материалов на тему кодировок, но все они касаются содержания фала, либо загрузки внешнего файла. А мне нужно создать файл с данными и именем файла русскими буквами. Я пробовала менять кодировку имени файла, но безрезультатно

Как создать файл?

Я делала так:

```
File docCase = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Files");
        docCase.mkdirs();
String fileName1 = "Файл"; 
String fileName2 = new String(fileName1.getBytes("utf-8"),"cp1251");
String fileName3 = fileName2 + ".xml";
myFile = new File(docCase.getAbsolutePath(), fileName3);
```

Comment: Сохраняйте тоже в utf-8, он ведь поддерживает кириллицу

Answer (score 0):

```
try (final Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Хелло.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
    writer.write("текст");
}
```

Без проблем создает файл с русским именем и русским содержанием.
А вообще, все зависит от кодировки `OS`, в какой `OS` в такой и сохраняйте, вот например у меня `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` - выводит `UTF-8`, в ней и нужно сохранять.